# What does it indicate if a professor from other departments is included in applied math department?

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, professorship, mathematics

Currently I am preparing for postgraduate application. My research interest is fluid mechanics. There are several professors whose research interests are similar to mine and all of them are included in both applied math department and some non-math departments, such as geophysics department. Most of their papers are published in Journal of Fluid Mechanics, which is one of the leading journals in that field. However, it seems that those papers do not involve advanced math knowledge, such as abstract algebra or analysis. Even epsilon-delta terminology seldom appears in those papers.

This slightly contradicts to my previous understanding. In the math department where I finished my undergraduate study, real analysis is a basic requirement for every postgraduate student. Does this mean the field of applied fluid mechanism does not require students with solid math background? What does it imply if a professor is included in applied math department? Does this indicate he/she will supervise a student with only math background? Or does this mean he/she has an intention to publish papers in math journals?

Comment: It means their peers consider them to be applied mathematicians.  Not all math requires algebra or analysis.

Comment: And not all applications of analysis require epsilons and deltas.

Comment: Im my experience, affiliate faculty are unusually common in applied math departments. In fact, in many applied math departments (such as Cornell: http://www.cam.cornell.edu/cam/people/faculty.cfm or Yale: http://applied.math.yale.edu/people/faculty), just about *every* faculty member is *from another department*.

Comment: @RaisinBread: I don't know about Yale, but at Cornell, there is no applied math department.  The web page you linked to is for a "center" which brings together various faculty with an interest in applied math, all of whom have appointments in ordinary departments.

Comment: It seems a little strange to infer that someone lacks knowledge of X because they wrote papers not referencing X.  Do you mean that when you look at the papers, you see specific mathematical content/formalism missing, to its detriment?  If so, that sounds like a good reason not to want to work with that faculty member.  I would say: find people whose work you are overall very interested in, and then write to them asking about what level of mathematical background they use in their work and require of the students.  Try to phrase the question as a question and not a judgment.

Comment: @RaisinBread I am from Cornell and my adviser is also affiliated with the Center for Applied Mathematics. However, he is primarily an electrical engineering. At Cornell, a "center" is an organizational structure  which combines faculty with overlapping and complementary interests under one formal mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Affiliate faculty are common in many university departments. This indicates faculty who have a departmental home (faculty line, voting rights, tenure and promotion line, office space) but for a variety of reasons are given courtesy appointments (sometimes called in the USA as 0 FTE appointments) in another department. This may be because they teach a crosslisted course or occasionally sit on doctoral committees of the other department, or occasionally just for the academic lulz (ie, they requested an affiliation and there was no reason to deny it).

Affiliate faculty <strike>rarely</strike> occasionally (depending on discipline and university) serve as chairs of doctoral committees and similarly are rarely/occasionally (depending on discipline) given students in that department to supervise. Their ability though to sit as members on committees is useful if you were to want to do a project in geophysics (in this case) but otherwise you can ignore them.

Note that this is different from faculty with dual appointments where their faculty line is split (0.5 FTE in one department, 0.5 in another). They have voting and advisory rights in both departments.

```
FTE = Full-Time Equivalent, the essential counting unit of faculty lines. 
A department with two full-time faculty and two joint-appointments would 
have 2*1 FTE + 2 * 0.5 FTE = 3 FTE
```

**TL;DR**: Don't worry about affiliate faculty. Focus on the core faculty and their strengths when making decisions.

Comment: _Affiliate faculty rarely serve as chairs of doctoral committees and are rarely given students in that department to supervise_ : I would beg to differ. I can point out numerous counter examples including my own. :)

Comment: To which part? The latter? And rare != never.

Comment: I would beg to differ with the use of the word "rare"  Perhaps this is influenced by discipline and field (and my own limited experience) but in the broader fields of computer science, mathematics, statistics, electrical engineering that I find myself in, this is quite common especially in my past two universities.

Comment: At least at my university, the question would be why a student would apply (and graduate from) an EE department if their committee chair was not a mainline EE faculty member. It would indicate a weakening of the standards of the EE department in that they would be seen as not capable of chairing their own students and have to rely on an outsider for this. At my school, PhD committee chairs must be fully appointed in the department. Secondary members (readers) may be from across the university and the world.

Comment: Rare exceptions can be made by the graduate school, but if we were to do this as *regular* practice the university would either tell us to: 1) cut it out; 2) transfer the line of the outside faculty to our department in part or whole; and/or 3) reconsider how we recruit and mentor our graduate students.

Comment: But I should add that I'm at a large R1 university. Smaller universities with smaller faculty bodies may be forced to do more sharing across faculty lines. So this may be a question of university size as well as disciplinary boundaries.

Comment: I would estimate that about 5% of the PhD students in my department (at a large R1) have a primary advisor outside my department. This is normal and accepted practice. University rules require a majority of the thesis committee to be from the student's home department, and every student is evaluated annually by department faculty in their research area, so there's little danger of weakened standards. And it's not because we're incapable of advising those students, but because the students found a better intellectual match elsewhere. After all, it's their degree.

Comment: @JeffE - what field are you in?

Comment: @JeffE - Also 1:19 (5%) would be considered rare in my book. If it would rise to 25%, wouldn't you agree that the university would start to raise questions?

Comment: @RoboKaren Computer science. The number is actually closer to 25% in some subfields that overlap with computer engineering. (CS faculty also advise CE students in those fields.) No, the university doesn't raise questions; if anything they _encourage_ cross-fertilization between departments.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect disciplinary differences, especially taking into account the OP's intent to go into an applied math field.