# What is an affiliate professor?

Tags: professorship

The answer to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37883/how-does-one-become-an-affiliate-professor) seems to indicate that an affiliate professor is effectively just a member of the department for administrative purposes. If that is the case, why is George H. Miley [both an affiliate professor and a professor](https://web.archive.org/web/20111130031023/http://www.ae.illinois.edu/people/faculty/miley.html) at the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign? Presumably his status as a professor would already grant everything that is granted to an affiliate professor.

(The above links to an old webpage, but the [current one](https://grainger.illinois.edu/about/directory/faculty/ghmiley) seems to say something similar, he is both an affiliate & an emeritus professor.)

Comment: Is his affiliate status in a different department?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/25785/17254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you give (https://grainger.illinois.edu/about/directory/faculty/ghmiley), the person is "professor emeritus" in one department, and "department affiliate emeritus" in another.

I can't speak to that university in particular, but in certain universities, a professor in a given department can only take on graduate students from that department.  Affiliate status with another department allows a professor to take on students graduate students from that department as well.